# Starting phrase for giving advice

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I want to give some advice casually. Consider this sentence,

> Just a reminder: If you think you can make someone's day please do it,
> cause the world need more love.

Here, I love the way the phrase "***Just a reminder***" has been put in at the beginning.

Similarly, I am looking for an introductory phrase to casually give advice. For example,

> Settling the issues with anger is easy, you must have the courage to
> actually explain to your child the actual thing.

I thought some phrases might be,

- Just an advice
- Just some casual thoughts

But you see, they are not really appropriate for my case. Can someone suggest better phrases?

Comment: 'An advice' is, I believe, non-standard; I don't think 'advice' has been countified as yet.

Comment: Giving advice without being asked is aggressive behavior in that it asserts authority. As such, one should ask permission before proffering advice. _Can I give you a piece of advice?_ is about as strong as you should go; _Do you mind if I suggest something?_ is less intrusive. Politeness is a good tactic if it really matters to you whether the advice is taken.

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> If you want my advice

or again

> If you ask me

Words like ***Frankly*** or ***If I were you/in your shoes***, could also introduce advice.

Answer (score 0):

"**Here's a tip**" is a well-known introductory expression (pragmatic marker: focusing: giving advice).

Rick Steves even uses it punningly in an article in [Smarter Travel](https://www.smartertravel.com/heres-a-tip-dont-stress-over-tipping/):

*- Here’s a Tip: Don’t Stress Over Tipping*

Comment: This usage can be misleading since it often refers to the giving of insider information as for betting or investing, or of a hint as to how to manage some practical affair such as cooking a steak. This is how your example uses it. The phrase *can* be used to give other forms of advice, but I don't think it's especially used that way.